# Change factor levels for variable over multiple data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have 4 data sets which I would like to get the percentage for each group for each data set. This is all fine using `prop.table(table(df1$group))` changing for `df2$group` and so on, but I would like labels on my tables. So I have converted the column to a `factor` and assigned appropriate `levels`, however this involves assigning the `levels` to each data set.

I have tried using `lapply` but I end up with `NA`s for the factor `levels`.

Here is some data

```
df1 <- data.table(id=(1:100), group= sample(5,100, replace=T))
df2 <- data.table(id=(1:100), group= sample(5,100, replace=T))
df3 <- data.table(id=(1:100), group= sample(5,100, replace=T))
df4 <- data.table(id=(1:100), group= sample(5,100, replace=T))

df1$group <- as.factor(df1$group)
df2$group <- as.factor(df2$group)
df3$group <- as.factor(df3$group)
df4$group <- as.factor(df4$group)
```

what I have tried:

```
df <- list(df1,df2,df3,df4)
df <- lapply(df,function(x) x[,group:=factor(group, levels = c("A","B","C","D","E"))])
```

but this returns changes the `levels` but results in `NAs`.

The data are all in `data.tables` and I am interested in 5 `factors` per `data.table`. I would also be interested in changing the `class` of multiple variables across multiple `data.tables` but for simplicity this could be another question.

Comment: Try changing `levels` to `labels`.

Comment: First step would be putting them into a single table, `dfs = list(df1, df2, df3, df4); DF = rbindlist(dfs, id="dfid")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify the `labels` that correspond to the `levels` present in the original data

```
lapply(df, function(x) x[,  group := factor(group, levels = 1:5, labels = LETTERS[1:5])])
```